# Interesting question regarding elementary functions

Tags: analysis, functions

I had this question at a test for a job interview and since and I didn't solve it.

Some time later i still can't figure it out, so any insight is helpful.

You need to write a function $f(x)$ such that $x^2 \leq f(x) \leq e^x$ for all real $x$ in $[0..100]$ and:

a) $f(x)$ touches $x^2$ 100 times and $e^x$ 100 times in $[0..100]$

b) $f(x)$ touches $x^2$ 100 times and $e^x$ 200 times in $[0..100]$

Also piece-wise definitions aren't allowed function must be elementary.

Comment: For example, $x^2+ \frac{1+\sin (kx)}{2}(e^x-x^2)$ for various $k$, and similar functions.

Comment: For part b), you could make use of the periodic function $g(x)=|\sin(2kx)|+|\sin(kx)|$ for suitable $k$. This has exactly two maximums (of equal value) between any two successive zeros.

Answer (score 1):

$e^x-x^2>0$ for all $x$ in that range, so you can multiply an appropriately-scaled sine function by this difference and add $x^2$ to solve the first. Something like
$$
f(x)=x^2+\frac{1+\sin(2\pi x)}{2}(e^x-x^2)
$$